# Ajax/href to express route with res.render

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a problem with calling a route via ajax/href and rendering a view.
So I want to edit data in a `TableView`. If I click on the edit button, it should redirect me to my edit view with the id of the data as a parameter. I tried it with `window.location.href` and via an ajax call.

```
$('#EditButton').click(function(id){
    var url1 = '/edit' + '/' + id
    window.location.href = url1;
    // $.ajax({
    //     url: url1,
    //     type: 'GET',
    //     error: function (e) {
    //         console.log(e);
    //     },
    //     success: function(data) {
    //         console.log('req for edit was a success');
    //     }
    // })
})
```

My route in express looks like this:

```
app.get('/edit/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log('Params Received Id: ' + id);

    db.findData(id, function(data) {
        console.log('Retrieved from DB: ' + data);
        res.render('editData', {
            name: data.name,
            desc: data.desc,
        });
    });
});
```

With `window.location.href` it at least shows the `editData` view, but I cannot access the passed parameter (name, desc) via handlebars. With the ajax call it shows the view in the console, not the browser; I don't know if the
data is passed. Does someone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you want your Handlebars template to have access to the `id` parameter, then pass that parameter to it along with `name` and `desc`.

Comment: I meant that I can not access the name and the desc I passed along with res.render.

Comment: Why not? What does your template look like?

Comment: It is not an issue of the template file. It is working fine, if I am not calling via ajax or href. Calling via ajax it don't even shows the html file, only in the console. And with href it redirects fine to the html, but it looks like handlebars engine is not working with this approach.

Comment: How do you "call" the template other than by an AJAX request or a document request?

Comment: Creating the route and calling it vial localhost:3000/edit/123456 manually via browser. It renders the html correctly and handlebars fills name and desc in the paricular fields.

Comment: I don't see why entering the URL manually would be any different than when assigning to `window.location.href. What URL is in your browser's address bar after the assignment? Are you sure there is an `id` in your click handler?

Comment: I have no idea why this is different. But while debugging, my handlebars helper is not called if the route is called with href. With entering the URL manually the hbs code is called without problem